# How do I hide Word and Excel from displaying on screen in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, excel-2007, office-interop

I am trying to hide Word and Excel from displaying when I am processing some documents.
I know it is capable of not even being displayed on the taskbar but hidden as a process but I can't seem to get that to work.
I am also not sure if creating excel tables or charts is causing this problem as well.

Any advice is appreciated.
Thank you.

Here is a code fragment that I currently have.

```
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object readOnly = true;
object addToRecentFiles = false;
object visible = false;

object filename = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.docx");

Word.Application word = null;
word = new Word.Application();
word.Visible = false;

Word.Documents documents = word.Documents;
Word.Document doc = documents.Open(ref filename, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref addToRecentFiles, ref missing, ref missing, true, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref visible, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
doc.Activate();
```

Comment: Post two questions: One for Word, one for Excel. You *might* get lucky and find one person who can answer for both applications. But if you ask separately you're sure to get answers very quickly. Use the [edit] link to change your question and remove the inappropriate tag. Since you've already an Answer for Word, I recommend you delete Excel from this question and post a new one for Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding the last line `.DisplayAlerts = false;` I have here to both your docs you've made there:

```
Word.Application word = null;
word = new Word.Application();
word.Visible = false;
word.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

Comment: Thanks! it appears to be working. Now I just need to get the excel that manipulate the charts to be hidden.

Comment: @amsga you would do the same thing to your Excel.Application object object. After creating it, set the `.DisplayAlerts = false` for it as well; just like what we've done with your `word` object. And if it works for you, please mark my answer as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark beside it.